# NASM label or instruction expected at start of line

Tags: nasm

I had trying assembly a file.
But it has some error.
How can I fix it? Why it failed?

I had assembly the following code using `nasm ipl.asm -o ipl.bin -l ipl.asm.lst`:

```
; Omitted because it is not important.

error:  mov si, failmsg
    call putstr

bl: hlt
    jmp bl

; Omitted because it is not important, too.
```

(above `ipl.asm`)

but it failed with:

```
ipl.asm:80: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
```

How can I fix it? Why it fail?

Comment: provide code and error message to help you resolve error faster,  is failmsg  declared? and note that  si  16 bit-short register,  mov register, memory  (is valid). need more info.

Comment: `bl` is a register name, you may need `$bl` or just rename it to something else to use as a label.

Comment: In the future, you should indicate which is line 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copied from the comment of @ecm. Thank her.)

`bl` is a register name, so we can't name a label using `bl`.